# Existence theory for first order scalar discontinuous ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Consider the scalar i.v.p. in ${\mathbb R}$
$$
x'=f(t,x), \;  t\in[0,T], \; x(0)=x_0,
$$
where $T\in {\mathbb R}$,   $T>0$, $x_0\in {\mathbb R} $, and $f:[0,T] \times {\mathbb R}\mapsto {\mathbb R}$ has the property:

(i) for each (Lebesgue) measurable  $y: [0,T] \mapsto {\mathbb R}$, the map $[0,T]\ni t\mapsto f(t,y(t))\in {\mathbb R}$ is measurable.

(ii) For almost all $t\in[0,T]$, $\sup_{x\in R}|f(t, x)|\leq l(t)$, where $l : [0, T] \mapsto R$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I am aware of  (several) results  showing  the existence of Carath'{e}odory solutions to the above problem,   in the case when $f$ is not necessarily continuous, but,  in addition to  (possibly stronger versions) of (i),  and (ii), one supposes that $f$ is  non-decreasing in some sense   (see. eg., https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.die/1368638179;  https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-97-03942-7, etc ).

QUESTION: is there any similar result proving the existence of Carath'{e}odory solutions to the above problem in the case when $f$ is discontinuous, but non-increasing?